# How to use a mono in another mono that have circular dependency

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a spring boot reactive app. Where I want to implement to create a user if it doesn't already exists. Like this:

```
fun userAlreadyExist() = Mono.error<UserDTO>(UsernameAlreadyExistException())

fun create(userDTO: Mono<UserDTO>): Mono<Void> {
    return userDTO.filter { userRepository.existsByNameIgnoreCase(it.username).block() == false }
            .switchIfEmpty(userAlreadyExist())
            .flatMap { createNewUser(it).then() }
```

What I really dislike is that I need to use `.block()` inside the filter. Is there a better way to do this?

The big issue is the circular dependency both have, since `UserRepository` needs to know the username and userDTO stream needs to know wether this already exists which returns a mono.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I used `filter()` instead what I should have used is `filterWhen()` which evaluates async Monos.

What I did:

```
fun create(userDTO: Mono<UserDTO>): Mono<Void> {
    return userDTO.filterWhen { innerUserDTO ->
        userRepository.existsByNameIgnoreCase(innerUserDTO.username).map { !it }
    }
            .flatMap { createNewUser(it) }
            .switchIfEmpty(userAlreadyExist())
            .then()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic here looks a bit strange - you can probably do something like:

```
fun create(userDTO: Mono<UserDTO>): Mono<Void> {
    return userDTO.flatMap {
               userRepository.findByNameIgnoreCase(it.username)
                             .flatMap(user -> userAlreadyExist())
                             .switchIfEmpty(createNewUser(it)) 
           }.then()
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I also need to call userAlreadyExist() since it returns a error mono ```private fun userAlreadyExist() =
            Mono.error<UserDTO>(UsernameAlreadyExistException())```

Comment: I've edited my answer; it still looks a bit convoluted and should be improved.